# iphone sdk system time vs user time

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, nsdate, nstimezone

I have an app that requires me to take an action after some period of time.  For example, if an user hasn't been inside the app in few weeks, when the user eventually starts the app, I have to ask them to put in a special code that was given to them when they installed this app. (this is an in-house app and i am being required to do this due to security concerns)

I am using the [NSDate date] method to retrieve the date when the user logs in and save it into a database.  I compare this saved date next time they open up the app and see how long its been since their last login.  The problem is that [NSDate date] gives the time that is effected by the time settings that can be changed manually by the user in the native settings app.  As you can probably tell, this causes lots of problems to my situation.  If the user is suppose to be put the special code after 3 weeks of inactivity, he can cause the app to show this screen by modifying the time in the native settings app or worse, get away from it by setting the time to a previous date that will be within 3 weeks of his activity.

Is there a way to get the "system time" instead of the "user time"?  I have looked into mach_absolute_time() but this gets reset after restart of the device.  Since the time of inactivity I will be comparing against is pretty large, chances are device would have been restarted by then.  I also thought of using network connection to get the time from servers outside the app, but lots of users won't have access to wifi where they use their iPads.  That will be my last resort solution if i can't find anything else.  Because of their location during usage, I am trying to use everything on the device itself.

Am I overlooking something simple here?  this seems too simple of a problem to not have an answer.  Please guide me toward the right direction.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not query a remote server for the time - lots of NTP servers about or just make a simple HTTP request to a php script on your own server. Of course if your app is likely never to be connected to the internet that could be a problem, but once you have a 3rd party time its quite easy to guess if the user has been playing with the clock.

Comment: the issue is that network won't be available all the time.  I do not want to rely on outside information.  somehow Apple is able to figure out the correct time, even when its in airplane mode, restarting the device and all.

Comment: But you only need one successful connection to cache the correct time/local time. Then you can use the iPod's local time for the offset to correct time until you see the network again.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an inhouse app (so you aren't constrained by Apples approval process), you could mark your app as doing some background stuff (voip or receiving location updates), so that the app will always be active and you'd be able to update some sort of an "unused" counter. Voip app will even be restarted by the OS after device reboot.

But of course it'll drain the battery somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

Either:  make having the actual time an essential feature of your app. This way the users will have a need to keep the time of the device current and can't go back three weeks

Or: mark the code as expired and save this information before the app informs the user. This will stop most user from setting the time back. Most will try once or twice, see that the app stays disabled and will give up.

You can also save the timestamp of the last successful execution and if that is more than a reasonable time frame in the future (remember summer/winter time) then consider it a "hack attempt". Put a CRC check (or whatever obscure idea you come up with) on that timestamp and save it too and you will stop a large number of script kiddies.

You can never stop the diehard hacker who search actively for every trick you might have put into the app. Just focus on the "average" user.